# creating a jqueryui selectable causes Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'selectable'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable

I have a ul which I turn into a selectable using:

```
jQuery(".ul01").selectable({
    filter: "li",
    selected: this.li01Selected
});
```

Obviously, on 'selected', I call a function that creates another selectable:

```
this.li01Selected = function(event, ui){
    jQuery(".ul02").selectable({
        ...
```

My problem happen when jQuery(".ul02").selectable({ is called, I get

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'selectable'"
```

I have tried var x = jQuery.noConflict() with the same outcome.
I have checked that only one jquery and jqueryui lib is imported.

I can only guess that its something to do with calling .selectable() within .selectable()...

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if you didn't include jQuery UI, or if you included a different copy of jQuery after it (so that the new `$` doesn't have the plugin).

Comment: so why would .selectable() work on the first ul01, but say "no method" immediately after?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is another library overwriting the `$`. As I know `prototype` also uses the `$`. When you call:

```
$(".ul01").selectable({
    filter: "li",
    selected: this.li01Selected
});
```

The `$(".ul01").selectable()` is executed immediately. But the `$(".ul02").selectable()` is only executed when you trigger an event on `.ul01`. In between, maybe another library or your own code overwrites the `$` variable

Comment: ...I have found one place where more jquery.min.js's are getting included.  But I thought var x = $.noConflict();  x("ul02").selectable({...  would solve that...and it doesn't.

Comment: @user2282496: you have to use it like this `var jq = jQuery.noConflict(); jq(".ul02").selectable(`. This relinquishes control of $ and use another variable to hold it because the $ will be overwritten by your jquery.min.js. But the best way is to avoid reloading the jquery.min.js.

Comment: Hi Khanh, turns out I was injecting another jquery.min.js by accident.  I have stopped injecting these by checking whether jQuery is already defined & loading/not loading as needed - but without success (still errors).  Also tried the var jd = ... method without success... thanks tho

Comment: @user2282496: if the problem still persists, I think that beside jquery.min.js, there are other scripts overwriting the `$` (such as prototype.js or even your own code somewhere)

Comment: thanks.  I think you're right - there is another jquery in my program.  However I cannot find where its coming from (and Chrome and Firefox developer tools/sources/resources only show files that are loaded - not scripts loaded via Jquery.load()) so, to get my project moving again I have reverted to using a simple click() handler... I will post bac if I have any further findings.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user2282496: good that you found it. Hope you get it working soon